# Correct interpretation of linear regression coefficient?

Tags: regression, linear-model

Let's say I'm running a survey and I ask "Are you confident in the economy, yes or no?"

Then I ask the respondent "are we spending too much or not too much on scientific funding?

I let the answer "yes" and "not too much" be 1, and the other two answers a 0.

Let's say I run an OLS model on the relationship and I get:

Scientific-funding-view_predicted = .009(confidence-in-economy) + B

Am I correct in interpreting this as **"the model predicts a respondent who becomes confident in the economy will increase their probability of believing the government is not spending too much on scientific funding by .9%"**?

I want to find a better way of wording in, but I can't seem to think of anything.

Thank you!

EDIT:

Let's say I ran a logistic regression, and let's say I got the exact same coefficient. How would I interpret this?

I take exp[.009] which is 1.009.

Would I interpret that, if someone doesn't think we are spending too much on the economy, the odds of them being confident in the economy versus not confident in the economy is 1.009?

Comment: I'd suggest fitting a logistic regression for this problem because your outcome is 0/1. This will lead to [nicely interpretable](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/odds_ratio.htm) results.

Comment: The phrase "who becomes" in your bolded sentence is a statement about causality, and not correlation.  Inferring causality from a regression in that way is anything but clear cut and easy.

Comment: Ok. I ran a logistic regression, and let's say I got the exact same coefficient. How would I interpret this?

I take exp[.009] which is 1.009.

Then I would say the odds of those that are confident in the economy AND don't think we spend too much on scientific funding to those who are not confident in the economy and think we don't spend too much is 1.009?

Comment: I have a lot of problems understanding the actual premise of your regression. Specifically, the answer coded as 1 seems to include two contradictory responses: "yes" to the question,  "are we spending too much or not too much on scientific funding?"; and, at the same time, "not too much". That makes it difficult for me to try to put in words your results.

Comment: As in the answer "yes" to the "are you confident in the economy" question is coded as a 1.

Then the answer "Not spending too much" to the question "are we spending too much or not too much on scientific funding" is coded as a 1.

0 to the other two possibilities.

The regression is to see if one's confidence in the economy affects their views on the government's investments into scientific funding.

Comment: Still a bit confused, I'm sorry. Should you consider a contingency table, and compare proportions?

Comment: The [page](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/odds_ratio.htm) I linked to has a section named "Logistic regression with a single dichotomous predictor variables [sic!]". This is exactly your situation. I suggest reading that section carefully.